# Given a line with unknown intercepts and finding locus of foot of perpendicular from origin?

Tags: geometry, locus

> Q) a variable line makes intercepts on coordinate axes . If the length
>   of the perpendicular on the line from the origin is the geometric mean
>   of the length of intercepts then find the locus of foot of
>   perpendicular drawn from origin ?

**My Attempt**

Given that distance $p^{2}=ab$
And C is a point $(h,k)$ therefore we have 
$h^2 +k^2=ab$ . I also know that $\frac{1}{p^2}=\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b^2} \Rightarrow a^2+b^2=ab$ .

Now how do i proceed ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $P=(x_0,y_0)$ is the projection of $O$ on the line.

The perpendicular to $OP$ through $P$ has equation:

$$ x_0 x + y y_0 = (x_0^2+y_0^2) $$
hence the lengths of the intercepts are given by $\frac{x_0^2+y_0^2}{x_0}$ and $\frac{x_0^2+y_0^2}{y_0}$.

The problem gives that $OP^2$ equals the product of these lengths, hence $x_0^2+y_0^2=x_0 y_0$ and $P$ belongs to the curve with equation $x^2-xy+y^2=0$, that is an ellipse.

Answer (score 2):

Let the general equation of a line (L1) be of the form x/a+y/b=1 
Let (h,k) lie on this line such that a normal line(L2) passing through this point intersects at the origin. 
Now we know that L1 is perpendicular to L2. Thus we get,

(k/h)*(-b/a)=-1

Which implies that:

k/h=a/b

Also, we know from the information provided in the question that 
ab=a^2+b^2, 
1=a/b+b/a

From the manipulation we did above we get,

1=k/h+h/k
which implies that

h^2+k^2=hk or x^2+y^2=xy.

Comment: Good answer , but use latex to make your answers much prettier . Thanks though